# is there a way to extract the where clause part in GraphQL hotchocolate

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

Hi I'm trying to use hotchoco with Dapper.
It there a way or method to extract the where clause part (filtering) from the IResolverContext ?

Idealy, for the below query

```
query{
  searchProjects(where: { name: { contains: "Bridge" } }){
    nodes{
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the "where", "name" , "contains", "bridge"

UPDATES:
The question is quite complicated actually. The thing I described is to translate an AST tree into SQL.
Will close this question.

Comment: Did some research, according to Hotchocolate team's road map,   they may have a feature to support dapper in future release.